# Laravel 4 append hashtag to routes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, routes, hashtag

I am having trouble appending hashtags to routes.

```
<a href="{{  route('content.create', ['#hash']) }}" ...
```

This gets me link generated like `content/create/%23hash`.

I tried appending directly like:

```
<a href="{{  route('content.create') . '#hash' }}" ...
```

but this just generates wrong route (it doesn't have `/content/create`, just appends `#hash` to current route

Comment: You can just put the hash after the closing curly brackets

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to put the hashtag outside the blade syntax

```
<a href="{{route('content.create')}}#hash'">
```